# Getting SSRS to aggregate as rows instead of columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, ssas-tabular

I've constructed a cube using SSAS, and I'm using that cube to fuel an SSRS report. Using Excel, I can generate reports as pivot tables from the SSAS source, and I'm trying to replicate some of that functionality as a report in SSRS instead.

Here's how I have the thing set up in Excel:

[image]

[image]

As you can see from the pictures, I have several stats that are being displayed per row rather than per column. The results that are displayed per row are aggregated statistics (sum, count, etc...).

How do I accomplish this same thing using SSRS? In Excel, it was simply a question of saying "Move to Row Labels".

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Matrix, set the column group to be by fiscal calendar .

Within the row group you will need to add additional detail rows and place each value on the row.

This should give you the desired results more of less.